# How to set session variables for CakePhp to work with Chrome?

Tags: session, cakephp, google-chrome, session-variables

I am working on a website using CakePhp. When uploading to the server and testing with Firefox everything works great.

When using Google Chrome, it seems like no session variables are created.

If I try to access the home page, I'm redirected to the login page first. After I login it doesn't redirect me to the home page, but to the login page again.

What I noticed is that the session variables are not created with Chrome but works fine with Firefox.

Comment: 1) Did you disable cookies on Chrome? 2) Does it work in Safari? 3) Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 1):

### Check this page

Here's the [link](http://www.pixelastic.com/blog/273%3alosing-session-request-cakephp-chrome).

Since when using a browser should change the server behavior ? Well I don't exactly know what Chrome is doing with the referer but it seems that it is altering it in some ways.
And cakePHP forces the setting of session.referer_check to true, thus checking that multiple requests with the same PHPSESSID comes from the same url.
As one posted on php.net :

> If you have a value specified for session.referer_check you may run
>   into difficulty when someone accesses your site and attempts to log in
>   with a mis-capitalized URL.  The logon will fail because any calls to
>   session_start() will result in the existing session being trashed and
>   a new one being created.  This becomes a bigger problem when the logon
>   is followed by a header("Location: ...") redirect, because the
>   session_start() at the top of the page will fail.

Those two settings combined, and you got a hell of a mess. I first found a quick fix by forcing the setting of session_start() in app/webroot/index.php. But after more reading and debugging I finally found the culprit.

## Hacking your way through the fix

There is no easy way to prevent cake from setting this setting, but you can define your own session handler in the Session.save configure key.
Just create file named session_custom.php in app/config/ and set Configure::write('Session.save', 'session_custom'); in your core.php file.
And in that file, just drop the following lines (copy/paste from cake_session.php)

```
ini_set('session.referer_check', '');                    // Killing this f***ing config that was causing so much trouble with Chrome
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);                    // No session id in url
ini_set('session.name', Configure::read('Session.cookie'));    // Using custom cookie name instead of PHPSESSID
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', $this->cookieLifeTime);    // Cookie like time, depending on security level
ini_set('session.cookie_path', $this->path);                // Cookie path
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am right then you are trying to set the session by retrieving the get value from the url 
if so the i suggest you use the classic php style url like
http://localhost/something/projects/view?id=4f0998ad-0538-4454-b51a-0ca46f441e7f
and use
$_GET['id'] in your controller to retrieve the value

I can say because i was facing the same trouble some time ago and searched through lots of blog to get an appropriate solution but got no where but using the above approach solved my p

Comment: doesn't look like cakephp solution

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/Config/core.php`

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake',
        'timeout'  => 14400,  // 4 hours 
        'cookieTimeout' => 14400, // 4 hours 
        'cookie' => 'cookiename',
        )
    );
```

check 'cookie' has no whitespaces in it, even underlines may cause a problem.

Had this problem some time ago and it took me a while to figure it out...